# _rawpy.so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit in buildozer(linux)

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy, buildozer

After installing rawpy in linux and building an apk through buildozer getting an error _rawpy.so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit.How to resolve it?

Comment: You probably need to write a build recipe for rawpy.

Comment: Is the text after "error" an error message? If that is the case, please format it so that it's identifiable as such.